# Use S3 pre-signed url to upload object with cache-control header on responses

Tags: amazon-s3

It seems unclear form the docs, but here is my goal:

1. Create a presigned url to upload a file to s3
2. Pass that url to the browser
3. The browser uploads a file selected by the user to s3 using the pre-signed url
4. When the object on s3 is requested, the "Cache-Control: max-age=604800" header is on the response.

I would LIKE to not have to rely on the client to do anything special to make this happen. Meaning, some signal to S3 that it should set the cache control header to that value would have to be present in the pre-signed url, but I can't tell from the docs or 50 google searches how that is accomplished.

Any illumination into how this can be accomplished would be great!